# AFHTTPSessionManager GET method syntax error?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

**Here's my code**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manger = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
[manger GET:requestUrl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```

**I got two error from Xcode.**

1. `Unknown type name 'id'`
2. `Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull __strong, int)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nullable)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull __strong, id  _Nullable __strong)'`.

Why is this happen?I had imported AFNetworking file in my header file.My Xcode version is 8.2,and AFNetworking version is 3.1.When I put this code snippet in my other project,there was no error.That was really confused me.Anyone can help?
[image]
I used Carthage to import AFNetwoking,still the same error.:(

Comment: this code is correct, please check other issue like semicolon(;) and {} are properly managed

Comment: indexing problem from xcode? have you tried restarting to reindex the project file?

Comment: @Joshua Yes,I had restart Xcode,still not work.And now I try to use Carthage to import AFNetwoking.

Comment: @Jecky Thanks.I had solved issue by recreating the project.

Answer (score 0):

your method should like this

```
-(void)callWebserviceWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_params
                        action:(NSString *)_action
                        success:(void (^)(id))_success
                        failure:(void (^)(NSError *))_failure

{
    if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) {

        //AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

       // manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:_action];
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
        [manager POST:url parameters:_params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"response = %@", responseObject);
        if( _success )
        {
            _success( responseObject ) ;
        }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            if( _failure )
            {
                _failure( error) ;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperation was AFNetworking2.0 class.I use AFNetworking 3.0

Comment: I had remove nullable, still not work.I doubt that there's something wrong with the cocoapods.

Comment: @jecky nullability type is not the reason for the error.

Comment: @Shawn_Rong This is my method for calling web service. I have used it and it is successful for me So try it

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:I recreate the project.And migrate the old code to new project.It works.But still know the reason why the old version code not work.